# Fetch random row from MySQL on click

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am creating a random quote generator and store the data in a MySQL database.
The code is working but it continues to fetch the same row and not a new random row everytime I click. But if I wait for say 30 seconds and click again, it works as it should. I just want it to work right away on click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".display").click(function() {                

  $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
    type: "GET",
    url: "display.php",             
    dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
    success: function(response){                    
        $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
        setTimeout(response, 5);
        //alert(response);
    }

});
});
});
```

I suspect the timeout function is not working properly as it takes longer to fetch a new row. I used the order by Rand() to get the random row. My PHP looks like this:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
$finds = "SELECT * FROM citater5 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($finds, $con) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$finds);

while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{   
echo "<aside class=\"citatout\">";
echo "<div id=\"paradiso\" class=\"text-vertical-center-q\">";
echo utf8_encode("<h1 class=\"animated fadeIn\" align=center>$data[0]</h1>");
echo utf8_encode("<h2 class=\"animated fadeIn\" align=center>$data[1]</h2>");
echo "</div>";
echo "</aside>";
}

?>
```

Why is a new row not being fetched every time?

Comment: It's because "order by rand()" doesn't do what you think it does. "order by foo" tells the SQL server to order by a column named "foo". What you could do is use PHP to generate a random ID and then ask SQL to return just that one result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the others said, `rand()` may not be the best to use, but I don't think it is what is causing your issue.  Most likely the result is being cached if it's displaying the same result for a short period of time.

You could try turning the cache off:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Or append the URL in the ajax call with a random number or timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if ORDER BY RAND() is working as you want it too.
 - I haven't really been working with PHP for a few years, but I would probably try something like this out:

```
<?php
    include("connect.php");
    $totalrows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM citater5"));
    $finds = "SELECT * FROM citater5 WHERE id='".rand(1,$totalrows)."'";
    $result = mysql_query($finds, $con) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$finds);

    $data = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    echo "<aside class=\"citatout\">";
    echo "<div id=\"paradiso\" class=\"text-vertical-center-q\">";
    echo utf8_encode("<h1 class=\"animated fadeIn\" align=center>$data[0]</h1>");
    echo utf8_encode("<h2 class=\"animated fadeIn\" align=center>$data[1]</h2>");
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</aside>";
?>
```

And - as you're only getting 1 result, theres no need to run it through a while().

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: You'd better make the number start at `0` and use it in a `LIMIT` clause as there is no guarantee that the ID's are numbered sequentially; there might be missing numbers and ID's higher than the total number of rows.

Comment: Didn't even think about that, you're totally right!